# How can I raise up a face to have it meet two edges?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

Very new to blender. I recently converted a .png to .obj and have been trying to work out the kinks with making it a proper 3d model. I've ran into an issue where there are certain edges that sit higher than the face that connects to them. I wondering if there was a way to lift up the face to meet the edges or lower the edges to meet the face? Also if anyone could let me know how to smooth out the faces marked with the X would be great. Thanks. [image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.